# Graphic novel following a female character getting recruited into a revolutionary anti establishment type war

Tags: story-identification, comics, dystopia, female-characters

In the early 90’s I was exposed to a graphic novel at my local library.  The content was post apocalyptic or dystopian and focused on a black female heroine who I think had a name that followed an American theme.  I want to say her name was Georgia Washington or something but I could be wrong.  It followed her, if I remember right, getting recruited into some revolutionary anti establishment type war and I remember it being violent as hell and adult.

Comment: Thank you that was it

Answer (score 6):

[Martha Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Washington_(comics)) by Frank Miller and Dave Gibbons

> Born on March 11, 1995 and died on March 11, 2095, Martha Washington
>   grew up in the Cabrini–Green housing project in Chicago (called "The
>   Green") with her mother and two brothers in abject poverty brought on
>   by the economic policies of the President Erwin Rexall. She is an
>   average student, but one who displays a gift for computer programming
>   and hacking.
>
> Her teacher, Donald, encourages her to be a better student and,
>   because he lives outside the Green, brings her contraband items. One
>   night, Martha shows up at Donald’s classroom and finds that he’s been
>   murdered by the Ice Man, a large thug who works for a local gangster
>   called the Pope. Before dying, Donald managed to stab the Ice Man in
>   the wrist. This distraction allowed Martha to seize his weapon, a
>   longshoreman’s hook, and plunge it into his shoulder. The Ice Man
>   chases her through the school to a locker room, but before he can kill
>   her, he dies of blood loss. Martha is later remanded to a psychiatric
>   hospital.
>
> In the institution, she discovers that experiments are being secretly
>   performed on children to genetically alter their minds, effectively
>   turning them into human computers. Their heads are covered with wires
>   plugged into their brains. Martha believes one of them resembles the
>   Raggedy Ann doll she played with as a child. This institution is
>   closed due to national budget cuts, and Martha is left homeless. She
>   later joins the PAX Peace Force, where her heroic tale begins. She
>   fights in many battles during the second American Civil War.
>
> During the second American Civil War, her mother and brother die when
>   Chicago is destroyed by a nuclear weapon.